# Windows XP 32 logo keeps loading

Tags: windows-xp, boot

this question is not new. But I'm not able to understand what people have suggested. can someone take the patience of explaining it in simple words to solve it. Pls.

Comment: when you say loading, does computer keeps restarting and won't boot past Windows logo ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I get the windows logo loading then a screen appearappears to choose from "safe mode etc etc". when I choose safe mode.. it gets stuck displaying a list of paths- multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS\system32\Drivers\Mup.sys.  this is one such from the list

Comment: Hey Ansh, Welcome to Superuser. Please add more information to your answer by editing it. Try Omar's Answer and Post The Blue Screen Error that you're getting :-)

Comment: I don't know how to Disable Automatic System Restart on System Failure. And so far I'm getting no Blue Screen Error

Comment: Most likely it is hard drive file corruption, one possible solution is to [run Spinrite on the hard drive](https://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm_), but this software is not free.

Comment: ware able to fix @Ansh

Answer (score 0):

I think that the computer is set to reboot automatically on system failure.

Try to tap F8 repeatedly while it boots up and select "Last Known Good Configuration". If that doesn't work, then try the "Disable Automatic System Restart on System Failure"

If you get blue screen Post the details back here

Take look at the [following link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-system/unmountable-boot-volume-stop-0x0000000ed/570c7f90-5869-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) it might help

Comment: Last known good configuration doesn't work. Again the same logo loading and after some time... a blue screen which says samsung and below that f2 for setup  f4 for recovery for about 2 secs and again  "safe mode options page appears" .  Also how do you try the "Disable Automatic System Restart on System Failure" ?

Comment: Yes. I finally got the blue screen after repeatedly tapping F8 and choosing to disable Automatic sys restart option..

Comment: Yes. I finally got the blue screen after repeatedly tapping F8 and choosing to disable Automatic sys restart option.. it says " A problem has been detected n windows has been shut down to prevent damage" UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME . If this is first time u see this stop error restart ur comp else follow steps. ( some steps given)  and then TECHNICAL INFORMATION: *** STOP: 0x000000ED (0x8A50C900,0xC000009C, 0x00000000,Ox00000000)